# show Method name expected when using StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap, structuremap4

i using StructureMap in my project for using DepencyInjection . I have 5 project in my solution.

I have `IUnitOfWork` interface in `DAL` and I Defnation Function of `IUnitOfWork` in `ApplicationDbContext` .

***ApplicationDbContext  :***

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationDBContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public void ForceDatabaseInitialize()
    {
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    #region IUnitOfWork Members

    public void MarkAsDeleted<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

.
.
.
```

now when I want to register `IUnitOfWork` in main project :

```
 public static class StructureMapDefnation
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder =
        new Lazy<Container>(defaultContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
    }
    private static Container defaultContainer()
    {
        var container = new Container(ioc =>
        {
            // map same interface to different concrete classes
            ioc.For<IUser>().Use<EfUserService>();
            ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(() => new ApplicationDbContext())();
        });
        container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        return container;
    }
}
```

it show me this error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0149  Method name expected    BimehKosarFinal E:\myproject\BimehKosarFinal\BimehKosarFinal\StructureMap\StructureMapDefnation.cs  28  Active

***in this line :***

```
ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(() => new ApplicationDbContext())();
```

whats the problem ? how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the last `()`, and write

```
ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
```

Or

```
ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<ApplicationDbContext>();
```